# What is this fonts name?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I can't find this font anywhere. Does anyone knows this font? Look how G, J, Q and R look.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [Montserrat Bold](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat), a Google font:

[image]